# Is there a way to get the deployed contract from a contract ABI?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, abi

Found an implementation of a dapp that uses a solidity contract but what's only available is the contract ABI from their project and not the solidity file.

Just wanna ask if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, you're asking if you can get the source code from the ABI? If so, the answer is no, you can't. The ABI only includes the information required to interact with a contract, i.e. the function names, parameters, return types, and event data.

Comment: Aww man haha alright then. A bit difficult to know what to code without a reference code especially if it uses a library. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: To add a bit, using a library or not is irrelevant. The ABI only has the signature of public functions and events, that its, their names, their parameter types, and their return types, nothing about their implementation, just an interface.